# Multiple file append in response object in node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, http

```
gfs.files.find({}).toArray(function(err, file) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log('file length ', file.length);
        if (file.length > 0) {
            file.forEach(function(each) {
                process.setMaxListeners(0);
                var mime = 'image/jpeg';
                res.set('Content-Type', mime);
                read_stream = gfs.createReadStream({ "filename": each.filename });
                read_stream.pipe(res, { end: false });
                done++;
            });
            read_stream.on('end', function() {
                process.setMaxListeners(0);
                if (done === file.length) {
                    res.send();
                }

            });

        } else {
            res.json('File Not Found');
        }
    }
});
```

It is not work properly.Only one file is shown in browser.what i do now?It   will be without any zip file.

Comment: Please state what is the goal of your code, what you tried, and what you may think is the problem.

Comment: I have huge image/audio/video file in database.I want to send all the file in single api response to the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

If your target clients are web browsers, then you can't, as the http protocol does not allow for multiple downloads for a single request.

May be you can think of creating an archive(zip) with requested files and send it.

Comment: Thanks for Response